# How do you clear Alexa music history?

Tags: alexa

How do you remove an item from Alexa's music history, as shown under the history tab of the music section in the Alexa app?

Answer (score 4):

Songs can be deleted from [recently played](https://music.amazon.com/recently/played) list in [Amazon Music](https://music.amazon.com) account.

1. Log into https://music.amazon.com
2. Browse to "Recents: Played" on left side menu.
3. From the list of songs, choose "Remove song from history" option in the sub-menu for the song to be removed.

Comment: Removing songs from the Amazon Music history, as you describe, does not remove the corresponding item from the Alexa music history.

Comment: @stovroz I just logged out and logged in the app and now I see recent played in app also cleared.